Intermittent WiFi Connectivity Issue: "No WiFi Adapter Found" in Ubuntu 23.10 with Intel AX210
I'm experiencing an issue with my (Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz (rev 1a)) wifi card on my desktop running Ubuntu 23.10. Initially, the WiFi functions correctly—I'm able to connect to networks and browse without any problems, confirming the WiFi card's functionality. However, at random intervals throughout the week, usually once a day, the WiFi disconnects and refuses to reconnect and sends the card into a 'locked state' that always displays a "No WiFi adapter found" message. I say locked sate because even upon attempting to toggle WiFi off and on through the UI and rebooting the system the "No Wifi adapter found" issue continues until some amount of time has passed.
System Specifications and Current Solutions Attempted:

The system and drivers are up to date.
I experienced this issue both on Ubuntu 22.04, and my current version 23.10. I did not experience this issue on Windows 11.
Kernel Version: 6.5.0-28-generic
The WiFi card is verified with lspci | grep Network, showing 0a:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz (rev 1a). This card is embedded in the motherboard: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B0BDTHQTJV/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1
Power management settings have been adjusted (wifi.powersave = 2 in the NetworkManager config file).
Restarting the NetworkManager service (sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager) doesn't alleviate the issue. It either persists in a disconnected state without displaying available networks or reverts to the "No WiFi adapter found" error.
Attempts to manually reset the link (sudo ip link set wlp10s0 down followed by sudo ip link set wlp10s0 up) result in a "RETNETLINK answers: Connection timed out" error.
A full system reboot temporarily resolves the issue, allowing the WiFi to connect and function normally. However this only temporarily fixes the issue, and usually I experience this locked state over multiple reboots.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue, or does anyone have advice on possible fixes, configuration adjustments, or diagnostic steps that could help identify and resolve the core problem?
Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.
Update
I tried various other methods, including the logging methods suggested by the comments and nothing stood out as to what the issue was. I did find a temporary solution to reset the wifi card by removing it and then re-enabling it manually. sudo lshw -class network  seemed to show the wireless card as being disabled, which is good and is the first sign I've seen of the system actually acknowledging a problem with it, but I'm not sure where to find the core issue here:
torrin@desktop:~$ sudo lshw -class network 
[sudo] password for torrin: 
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6E(802.11ax) AX210/AX1675* 2x2 [Typhoon Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: wlp10s0
       version: 1a
       serial: bc:09:1b:11:66:65
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic firmware=86.fb5c9aeb.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-86.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:24 memory:fc500000-fc503fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller I225-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       logical name: enp11s0
       version: 03
       serial: a0:36:bc:ac:ca:fc
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic firmware=1082:8770 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:36 memory:fc200000-fc2fffff memory:fc300000-fc303fff
torrin@desktop:~$ sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
torrin@desktop:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
torrin@desktop:~$ sudo lshw -class network 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6E(802.11ax) AX210/AX1675* 2x2 [Typhoon Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: wlp10s0
       version: 1a
       serial: bc:09:1b:11:66:65
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic firmware=86.fb5c9aeb.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-86.uc ip=192.168.1.44 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:24 memory:fc500000-fc503fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller I225-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       logical name: enp11s0
       version: 03
       serial: a0:36:bc:ac:ca:fc
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic firmware=1082:8770 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:36 memory:fc200000-fc2fffff memory:fc300000-fc303fff
torrin@desktop:~$ 

Some more info:

Windows was completely wiped from the system and the drives have all been formatted, this is not a dual-boot system.
Restarting NetworkManager throws Ubuntu into a very laggy state and doesn't resolve the issue.
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi & sudo modprobe iwlwifi resets the card and fixes the issue immediately, but doesn't permanently resolve the intermittent outages.
I've also updated to 24.04 and the issue persisted. I want to re-iterate that this system ran fine on windows

Here is the output of the iwlwifi driver, not really familiar with this command and don't know what to look for:
torrin@desktop:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi

This whole output is quite a lot of text so I can't post it all here but here is a summary of the errors:

"Error sending SYSTEM_STATISTICS_CMD: time out after 2000ms."
"Current CMD queue read_ptr 1938 write_ptr 1939"
"WARNING: CPU: 24 PID: 1400 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2237 __iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1a0/0x1b0 [iwlwifi]"
"HW error, resetting before reading"
"iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers"
"Failed to start RT ucode: -110"
"Failed to synchronize multicast groups update"
"Failed to trigger RX queues sync (-5)"
"WARNING: CPU: 24 PID: 163 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/../iwl-trans.h:1423 iwl_mvm_wait_sta_queues_empty+0xbc/0x110 [iwlmvm]"
"iwl_trans_wait_txq_empty bad state = 0"


Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager. Read man journalctl NetworkManager service. Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

Is the hybrid shutdown in Windows disabled?

@waltinator I've added an updated section, none of those logs from NetworkManager appeared to indicate an issue from what I could tell (I probably missed osmething).

@Jeremy31 Windows is not installed on the system anymore and the os drive was formatted when installing ubuntu.

I'm facing a similar same issue, I will post a clearer update later, but from what it looks like, power-saving will need to be disabled from multiple layers - network manager, driver options, and bios settings

I fixed this problem on Ubuntu 24.04 by installing the linux-modules-iwlwifi-generic package:
sudo apt install linux-modules-iwlwifi-generic

Now everything is working fine.
